# PHP Access 2 Databases

Tags: php, mysql

Currently for our login system etc we use a connect.php file with the following contents

```
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re currently experiencing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('localhost', 'x', 'x') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('x');
```

We are currently developing a system that we would like users to be able to add devices to their account

The main table we have stores all the users info e.g. First Name, Last Name, Email, Password

To this table we are adding the following fields - Device 1, Device 2, Device 3

Along side this we would also like to have access to another database, we want to hold the device id's in the main database so we know who owns what devices.

The second database will consist of Device ID, Lat, Long, Time

We would like to be able to read out of either database, I'm not sure how we would specify the database to connect to as I've only ever dealt with the one database

I'm not sure if its doable or if i'm going about it the totally wrong way - Both databases will be on the same server and we can assign the same user to both databases if that helps

Thanks

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure of your question. Of course you can have multiple tables in a database.

Comment: On another note as of `PHP 5.5.0` `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **You should not use `mysql_*` functions as the are deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/MySQLi) or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) for this.**

In Mysql the solution is to use the link identifier returned by [mysql_connect](http://php.net/mysql_connect). But if you use MySQLi or PDO you need to create those object first and use that object. OOP interface of MySQLi has NO concept of link identifier. Read [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) from PHP manual that helps you to migrate. For PDO use [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) to learn.

For MySQLi extension, its already a object and the object contains database information.

```
$db1 = new mysqli(...);
$db2 = new mysqli(...);

// sending query in database 1
$db1->query("...") 

// sending query in database 2
$db2->query("...")
```

---

For MySQL extension, [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect) returns a links identifier. You should save it in a variable and use it.

```
$link1 = mysql_connect();
mysql_select_db($dbnane, $link1);

$link2 = mysql_connect();
mysql_select_db($dbnane, $link2);

In query you should use it like this,

mysql_query($query, $link1); // query in first db

mysql_query($query2, $link2); // query in second db;
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't use as mysql_* functions are deprecated:

```
$database_handler_1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
// The fourth parameter is for "new link" 
$database_handler_2 = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password", true); 

// Insert as parameter the database handler
mysql_select_db('database1', $database_handler_1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $database_handler_2);

// And run queries with the database handler as second parameter:
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $database_handler_1);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $database_handler_2);
```

Can use instead:

```
$database_handler_1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1', $user, $pass);
$database_handler_2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database2', $user, $pass);
$database_handler_1->query('SELECT * from FOO')
$database_handler_1->query('SELECT * from BAR')
```

(Look @ the full PDO documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: This answer would be better if it didn't use the deprecated mysql functions (i.e. use mysqli or pdo instead)

Comment: And you are absolutely right of course. Will edit it ASAP :)